# How to change the path in which are stored the media modules files and images?

Tags: 8, media

When using media entity reference fields, is it possible to change the path where are stored the files and how?
Is it possible to store them in the private folder?

Comment: If you have set the private and public folder in the site it should show a radio button for selection in Field's Settings Tab

Answer (score 0):

i have found the radio button for selecting private in

```
/admin/structure/media/manage/file/fields/media.file.field_media_file/storage
```

how to change folder path , using possibly tokens?